# Xamarin - How to actually customize a slider's thickness?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, user-controls

As in the title I'm having trouble customizing a Xamarin Slider's thickness. The problem is there isn't even such property!

A few days ago I had the same problem with a frame but I managed to find a third party code that does the job but with this current problem all I could find is barely sufficient (literally half-assed) workarounds.

So does anyone know a proper way to solve this problem?

By proper I mean:

- It must be cross platform.
- Well it should actually solve the problem!

[image: What I'm trying to do]

I'm trying to accomplish what's in the picture.

All help's appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the ThumbImage property of the slider to add the circular image but I don't know about the thickness.

Comment: Thanks. I already knew how to do it. The real problem is the thickness.

Comment: @EfeZaladin I usually use the SyncFusion library for Xamarin did you take a look at that?

Comment: Yes in fact I did. They don't have what I'm looking for.

Comment: There actually are other libraries too. I will see if they have something that will work.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I will search some other libraries too I guess.